# Restricted Assignment in Python's List Comprehensions?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The example is stolen from [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) but my goal has a restriction so that output is `[8,12,-54]`. How can you do it with list comprehensions? I need to somehow refer to the index like `x_{i}*y_{i}`, I am hesitant to add a loop there, is there some elegant solution?

```
>>> vec1 = [2, 4, 6]
>>> vec2 = [4, 3, -9]
>>> [x*y for x in vec1 for y in vec2]
[8, 6, -18, 16, 12, -36, 24, 18, -54]
```

Comment: @Rafe: the output is the restriction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[x * y for x, y in zip(vec1, vec2)]
```